# Firefox 4.0 Refresh and Go do not work

Tags: firefox

If I load my Firefox browser before my internet connection is connected, my tabs will obviously not load in Firefox.

However, once I am connected, and I go back to each tab, pressing F5 or the refresh button will do nothing, nor will clicking the arrow "Go" button do anything.

I have to load a new tab, and copy and paste the bad tab's address.

Is there logic or design to this, or this a bug (or user error)?

Update: I am using Firefox 4.0

Comment: This behaviour also occurs if Firefox knows it is online, and can't load a URL, which is working in another browser.  Pressing F5 or Refresh will not reload the page, even it loads correctly in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if Firefox is started without internet connections is entering the "Work offline" mode. You can change this from File -> Work Offline (should not be checked).

Comment: Alt + F to open the menu in FF4 (since it is invisible by default)

Comment: Under the File menu, Work Offline was already un-ticked, indicating Firefox was not working offline.